# convert string to u_char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I have two functions

```
foo(const string &value)
{
  bar(...)
}

bar(const u_char *value, size_t len)
{
  // do something
}
```

How do I convert a const string into a u_char *? I believe I can get size_t by using the sizeof() function.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Is there any difference between `uchar` and `u_char`, and are both type aliases of `unsigned char`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant u_char and not uchar. I have edited code. I don't believe there is such thing as uchar.

Comment: @user1314238: There's no such thing as a `u_char` in standard C++. What's the `u_char` type, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion from string to char* is done by using `c_str()`.

Regarding the `u_char` conversion, I don't think it's any different.

This will help you : [MSDN string converison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes thank you! I figured this out just 1 minute ago while looking at string api.

Also, I will need to typecast the result to (u_char *)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the c-style string representation of std::string using `c_str()` function. Simply call `bar((u_char)value.c_str(),value.length())`. signedness should not matter for c-style string.

Comment: This is incorrect, as `bar` takes a `u_char const*`, not a `u_char`.

Comment: sorry i've incorrectly assumed `u_char` was same as `unsigned char`

Answer (score 1):

`bar` can be called as follows (assuming `u_char` is some kind of `char`):

```
bar(reinterpret_cast<u_char const*>(value.c_str()), value.size())
```